# printing InfModel earlier changes printed representation later?

Tags: java, jena, jena-rules

I'm getting a strange effect in Jena 2.5.5 (on Linux) where I am playing around with the inference API. The following code is a stripped down version. I am creating an initially empty Model and a generic rule reasoner. I add a reflexivity rule for a certain statement. I attach the reasoner to the model to get an InfModel. Then I create the matching statement and add it to the Model.

Result: InfModel contains both the statement and its reverse. So far so good, that's what it's supposed to do.

Now, when I `System.out.println()` the InfModel prior to adding the matching statement to Model, the result is completely different: the rule seems not to fire and thus, InfModel will end up not containing the reverse of the original statement.

How does writing the model to the console change the functionality of the code? Is this behavior documented?

```
import java.util.*;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.*;

/**
 * Describe class <code>RuleTest</code> here.
 */
public class RuleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /* create model */
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

        /* output model */
        System.out.println("original model : " + model);
        System.out.println("-----");

        /* collect rules */
        List<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<Rule>();
        Rule rule = Rule.parseRule("[ (subject predicate object) -> (object predicate subject) ].");
        rules.add(rule);

        /* create rule reasoner */
        GenericRuleReasoner reasoner = new GenericRuleReasoner(rules);

        /* attach reasoner to model */
        InfModel infModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, model);

        /* output model */
        //-----------------------------------------------//
        // commenting the following line in/out changes  //
        // the output of (*) below in Jena 2.5.5 ?!?!?!  //
        //-----------------------------------------------//
        //System.out.println("inference model: " + infModel);        
        System.out.println("=====");

        /* add facts to original model */
        Resource s = model.createResource("subject");
        Property p = model.createProperty("predicate");
        RDFNode  o = model.createResource("object");
        Statement stmt = model.createStatement(s, p, o);
        model.add(stmt);

        /* output models */
        System.out.println("original model : " + model);
        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println("inference model: " + infModel); // (*)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a quick look at the relevant source and it appears that you have two options:

- If you want to make changes to the base *model* and then be sure that they propagate to the *infModel*, then you have to call *infModel.rebind()* after having made the changes and before you "ask" the *infModel* anything.
- You can use the *infModel* directly (instead of *model*) to create and add the statement's elements and the statement itself.

I know this does not directly answer your question, but it may solve your problem (which, btw, seems to be caused by reification triggered by the *toString()* method in *ModelCom* - the parent class of *InfModel*).

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that model.toString() has side-effects. I have not looked at the JENA source, so I can't be sure, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I think it's not only "likely" but also completely obvious that toString() must have side-effects. Which is certainly unexpected, but perhaps my experience with Jena is just too little to know what's going on. In any case, I could not find any documentation of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It's now a few years later and Jena is in the 2.10.x series.  When the indicated line is commented out, the output of your program is:

```
original model : <ModelCom   {} | >
-----
=====
original model : <ModelCom   {subject @predicate object} |  [subject, predicate, object]>
-----
inference model: <ModelCom   {object @predicate subject; subject @predicate object} |  [object, predicate, subject] [subject, predicate, object]>
```

and the string representation of the InfModel contains two triples. When the line is uncommented, the output is:

```
original model : <ModelCom   {} | >
-----
inference model: <ModelCom   {} | >
=====
original model : <ModelCom   {subject @predicate object} |  [subject, predicate, object]>
-----
inference model: <ModelCom   {subject @predicate object} |  [subject, predicate, object]>
```

and the second string representation of the InfModel has only one triple, so the difference is still observed. (I included the output here, because in the question it isn't clear *what* difference was being observed.)

The short answer is that this happens because you're being sneaky and modifying `model` without telling `infModel` that you changed the underlying `model`.  To address this, you should add a call to `infModel.rebind();` after you update `model`.  That is, you would now have:

```
model.add(stmt);
infModel.rebind();
```

When you do this, you'll get the same output in both cases. With the line commented:

```
original model : <ModelCom   {} | >
-----
=====
original model : <ModelCom   {subject @predicate object} |  [subject, predicate, object]>
-----
inference model: <ModelCom   {object @predicate subject; subject @predicate object} |  [object, predicate, subject] [subject, predicate, object]>
```

With the line uncommented:

```
original model : <ModelCom   {} | >
-----
inference model: <ModelCom   {} | >
=====
original model : <ModelCom   {subject @predicate object} |  [subject, predicate, object]>
-----
inference model: <ModelCom   {object @predicate subject; subject @predicate object} |  [object, predicate, subject] [subject, predicate, object]>
```

My guess here is that writing the string representation of the InfModel doesn't cause any  inference to be performed unless no inference has been performed yet, and then prints the underlying model and then any additional triples that are inferred.  As a result:

- In the first case (when you print `infModel` just once) it hasn't done any inference yet, so it consults `model` and does the appropriate inference and gets the additional triples.  Then it prints `model`'s triples and then the inferred triples.
- In the second case (when you print `infModel` twice), the first time you print `infModel`, it consults `model` and does some inference, but `model` is empty, so there are no additional triples, and then it prints `model`'s triples and the additional inferred triples (there are none).  Then, the second time `infModel` is printed, inference has already been performed, so it prints `model`'s triples (but there's an extra one) and any inferred triples (there are none, because no more inference was performed).

The call to `rebind()` after adding triples to `model` means that in the second case, the additional inferred triples are available at the time of printing.